# Create a ksh function that unsets itself

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, ksh, scripting-language

In ksh93 this barfs:

```
source foo.ksh
foo die
```

when foo.ksh contains just:

```
foo() {
  echo Foo!
  if [[ "$1" = "die" ]]; then
    unset -f foo
  fi
}
```

in bash, it works. How can a function unset itself in ksh?

Comment: `ksh93 this barfs` -barfs how?

Comment: Memory fault(coredump)

Comment: Did you compile your own ksh? Your function works for me with ksh 93u+ and an ancient 88i

Comment: Mysterious! Prompted by your comment (and the one below by @mona_sax) I searched more, and finally tracked down a system where this works. The system is running CentOS. In all others I've tried (which are: a Ubuntu laptop, a Debian server, a couple of Ubuntu servers, an OS X laptop) it barfs. The version of ksh in all cases that I've tried is 93u+; in the case of the laptops and one of the servers (the Debian one) ksh was installed from packages, for the other server I don't know.

Comment: Also works on Red Hat Enterprise Server Santiago with ksh93t+. Maybe the problem is a Debian thing?

Comment: @user1093043 : Tracing a system where it works is  a big waste of time. Why didn't you debug the script instead using tools like the one suggested in this [page](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/unix/ksh/ch09_01.htm). If you compiled ksh use gdb to see where the `Memory Fault` happens.

Comment: @mona_sax: The variety of systems both under my control and not that exhibit the problem shows that this is not the result of something special I've done with ksh. In particular, as I mentioned, on several of these systems ksh is not compiled from source.

Answer (score 0):

The same works in `ksh` too. Consider `foo.ksh` is :

```
foo()
{
    echo "Bar"
    if [ "$1" = "die" ]
    then
    unset -f foo
    fi
}
```

Consider `main.ksh` is :

```
source foo.ksh
foo die
foo # you haven't checked if the function is unset or not
```

Gives you :

```
bar --> first call
main.ksh[10]: foo: not found [No such file or directory]  --> second call
```

Check it [[ here ]](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_ksh_online.php).

Comment: I don't know about the website you cite, but I have checked your code (which matches mine in all important ways) in local and remote shells (multiple Universities, my VPS, within my local net) and it always gives a memory fault.